# What terminology distinguishes questions that define goals from those that accomplish them?

Tags: terminology, metaphilosophy, introduction-to-philosophy, questions, wisdom

I will soon give a technical talk in which I want to stress the importance of asking the right questions. I propose to use a philosophical analogy; comparing the questions "How do I live a good life?" and "what is the nature of a good life?". That is, questions directed toward solving a problem compared with questions directed toward defining a problem.

My questions here are these. Do philosophers distinguish these two types of question? If so, is there a terminology that they use? Did any any well-known philosopher stress this distinction in their work?

Comment: idk if you meant it with this tenor, but you could look into Heidegger's 'idle talk'

Comment: It seems that the "how" question requires some view (even if implicit) on the "what" question? They don't seem like independent choices of question.

Comment: I would discriminate between "definition" and "action".

Comment: Your example seems to fall under the distinction between prescription and description, how things should be vs how they are, ["ought" vs "is"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem), which is well-known in ethics. [Values vs facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact%E2%80%93value_distinction) (your "goals" vs "nature"), [normative vs positive statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_statement) express closely related distinctions.

Comment: Sellars discussed the "manifest image" concerned with practical everyday know-how and the "scientific image" focused on theoretical understanding of know-what. There's a famous ancient [problem of criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_the_criterion) for the 'paradox' of the 2 questions: *Particularist theories organize things already known and attempt to use these particulars of knowledge to find a method of how we know, thus answering the second question set. Methodist theories propose an answer to question set two and proceed to use this to establish what we, in fact, know...*

Comment: Thanks for these interesting responses. The point of my talk will be that in my branch of engineering much effort is directed toward goals that may not be all that valuable, and I suspected that there should be some philosophical analog. Sort of like a good life being either wealth or happiness,  and I want to stress the importance of putting effort into defining better goals, even if that is harder than chasing the goals you have.

Comment: Engineering is most often focused on the established scientific image of know-what along with the know-how art of balancing different goals such as safety, reliability, efficiency, ease of maintenance, etc. So it's hard to say which goal is absolutely valuable without a spec context or use case. OTOH engineering often employ various tests such as intrusion, regression, stress tests or even model checking to define or further clarify those different goals. Since engineering is all about trade-off of goals, in this sense it's reduced to design different types of tests for the said trade-off...

Answer (score 1):

> How do I live a good life?" and "what is the nature of a good life?". That is, questions directed toward solving a problem compared with questions directed toward defining a problem... Do philosophers distinguish these two types of question?

Absolutely! Human beings are [teleological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology) [agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agency_(philosophy)). We have values ([axiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiology)), set goals, and then problem solve to bring about a change in the state of the world or our own thinking. It is related to the idea that human beings are [intentional (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/) agents who manifest [direction of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_of_fit) in their thinking. The pursuit of [eudaimonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudaimonia) is an impetus for philosophy. It is a question that circles around what it means to have a worldview and [meaning of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meaning_of_life).

'What is' is the wh-phrase that indicates that the question is [ontological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology) in nature. 'How do I know' invokes a type of philosophy that is [epistemological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology). Originally, 'How do I achieve' would have been an epistemological question in the sense of Greek [techne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Techne) to which today we might be tempted to call it a technological question. Instead, we tend to rely on the [philosophy of engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_engineering) when it comes to practical matters in the real world.

But when you say "How do I achieve a good life", you aren't talking techne and engineering, you are instead talking about [wisdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom) in the classical sense. Thus, this type of question is generally one answered by theologians (who purport to give us guidance from a [divine source of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divinity)) and classical philosophers (who tend to rely on [ethical theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics)). These days, ethical theorists are often heavily participatory in science and have a [naturalized epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalized_epistemology). Of those on the scientific end working on this sort of question, the most famous of them are generally the [humanist psychologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanistic_psychology) and [positive psychologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_psychology). Both of these groups borrow heavily from the philosophical definition of [existentialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism) which dwells on personal meaning and the meaning of life.

Comment: +1 "teleological" was the first word that came to me when reading the question too. Great answer, complete and robust!

Comment: @IoannisPaizis I suspect more readily to you than me given your name suggests that you might be familiar with 'telos' from a young age. :D